# for loop has 7 values to scroll through, but I get 8 outputs

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, new-operator

My code is the following:

```
smallest_so_far = -1
print("Before:", smallest_so_far)
for the_num in [9, 41, 12, 3, 74, 15, -3]:
    if the_num < smallest_so_far:
        print(the_num, "is smaller than", smallest_so_far)
        smallest_so_far = the_num
    print(the_num, "is not smaller than", smallest_so_far)

print("After:", smallest_so_far)
```

But why does it check -3 with -3 again in the end, if it already did one line before? I thought it was supposed to scroll through each and every value inside the "in" once.

Output:

```
Before: -1
9 is not smaller than -1
41 is not smaller than -1
12 is not smaller than -1
3 is not smaller than -1
74 is not smaller than -1
15 is not smaller than -1
-3 is smaller than -1
-3 is not smaller than -3
After: -3
```

Comment: You need to put that third print in the `else` clause of your `if` statement. You would have noticed this more if you had chosen 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought it was supposed to scroll through each and every value inside the "in" once.

It does, but for each value there is one `print` that is executed in any case, plus another `print` that is executed if the condition (`the_num < smallest_so_far`) is true. So for each value, you get 1 or possibly 2 lines of output.

In your case, you got 2 lines of output only one of the values, so in total 8 lines of output for 7 values. But if the order of input values was different, there could have been even more lines of output (up to 14).

If you want that the second `print` is not executed if the first was executed, you need to either use an `else` part for the `if` statement (so that *either* the `if` part *or* the `else` part is executed), or you can use a `continue` statement that skips the rest of the loop iteration if the condition was true.

Option 1, using `else`:

```
for the_num in [9, 41, 12, 3, 74, 15, -3]:
    if the_num < smallest_so_far:
        print(the_num, "is smaller than", smallest_so_far)
        smallest_so_far = the_num
    else:
        print(the_num, "is not smaller than", smallest_so_far)
```

Option 2, using `continue`:

```
for the_num in [9, 41, 12, 3, 74, 15, -3]:
    if the_num < smallest_so_far:
        print(the_num, "is smaller than", smallest_so_far)
        smallest_so_far = the_num
        continue
    print(the_num, "is not smaller than", smallest_so_far)
```

Comment: One more question: would you use option 1 or 2? As I said before I solved my problem with option 2 before, but 1 seems better.

Comment: It depends. If there is more code that should not be skipped, you can't use `continue`.

Answer (score 2):

You need an [else](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/if-elif-else#what). The code will still run the

```py
print(the_num, "is not smaller than", smallest_so_far)
```

no matter what.

So you would change your code to

```py
smallest_so_far = -1
print("Before:", smallest_so_far)
for the_num in [9, 41, 12, 3, 74, 15, -3]:
    if the_num < smallest_so_far:
        print(the_num, "is smaller than", smallest_so_far)
        smallest_so_far = the_num
    else:
        print(the_num, "is not smaller than", smallest_so_far)

print("After:", smallest_so_far)
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert the print inside of an else clause:

```py
smallest_so_far = 40
print("Before:", smallest_so_far)
for the_num in [9, 41, 12, 3, 74, 15, -3]:
    if the_num < smallest_so_far:
        print(the_num, "is smaller than", smallest_so_far)
        smallest_so_far = the_num
    else:
        print(the_num, "is not smaller than", smallest_so_far)

print("After:", smallest_so_far)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the IF statement within loop without ELSE statement, thus it is Printing both statement.
use following

```
if the_num < smallest_so_far:
    print(the_num, "is smaller than", smallest_so_far)
    smallest_so_far = the_num
else:
    print(the_num, "is not smaller than", smallest_so_far)
```